# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got a very peculiar encoding problem. I've looked at plenty of questions about this error with no actual answers. I am aware of Unicode issues in Python, so I start every file with:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

However, I still get `UnicodeDecodeError` when I run my software. Moreover, the following code works:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
g = " "
s = "2 000€"
if g in s:
    print s
```

The error occurs at:

```
if gap not in tokenString:
```

`tokenString` string contains Unicode. The funny thing is that if I try to print it just before that line it prints without an error.

What could be the cause of that? I feel like I'm missing something and I don't understand what.

**EDITED**
`gap` is of type `unicode` and `tokenString` of type `str`.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback. Are you printing Unicode data to the Windows console or a Unix terminal? Then see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails.

Comment: What type is `gap`? What type is `tokenString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to solve your problem for sure, but I can make a guess:

If `gap` is a `str`, and `tokenString` is a `unicode`, this line:

```
if gap not in tokenString:
```

… will try to convert `gap` to `unicode` to do the search. But if `gap` has any non-ASCII characters—e.g., because it's a Unicode string encoded into UTF-8—this conversion will fail.

For example:

```
>>> if 'é' in u'a':
...    print 'Yes'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You will get the same problem if `gap` is a `unicode` and `tokenString` is a `str` holding non-ASCII:

```
>>> if u'a' in 'é':
...     print 'Yes'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And you'll also get the same problem, or similar ones, with various other mixed-type operator and method calls (e.g., `u'a'.find('é')`).

---

The solution is to use the same type on both sides of the `in`. For example:

```
>>> if 'é'.decode('utf-8') in u'a':
...     print 'Yes'
```

No error.

---

The larger solution is to *always* use one type or the other *everywhere* within our code. Of course at the boundaries, you can't do that (e.g., if you're using `unicode` everywhere, but then you want to write to an 8-bit file), so you need to explicitly call `decode` and `encode` at those boundaries. But even then, you can usually wrap that up (e.g., with `codecs.open`, or with a custom file-writing function, or whatever, so all of your visible code is Unicode, fill stop.

---

Or, of course, you can use Python 3, which will immediately catch you trying to compare byte strings and Unicode strings and raise a `TypeError`, instead of trying to decode the bytes from ASCII and either misleadingly working or giving you a more confusing error…

Comment: The problem was that `gap` was loaded using the `json` module, which created `unicode` objects, which I didn't know about. I thought I was using the same `str` type consistently.